# Trait is not fired when I use the constructor

Tags: php, laravel, traits

My trait is not fired when I use the constructor of the class. My project use laravel 7.0

```
trait LogUserDB
{
    public static function bootLogUserDB()
    {
        self::creating();

        self::updating(
            function ($model) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                if ($user !== null && $user->id >= 0 && Schema::hasColumn($model->table, 'updated_by')) {
                    $model->updated_by = $user->id;
            }
        });

        self::deleting();
    }
}

abstract class AbstractBaseModel extends Model
{
    use LogUserDB;

    public function loadInfoSchema(){}
}
```

And that is my class that I can't use the construtor

```
class EmailsModel extends AbstractBaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'cad_emails';
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function __construtor($request){
        /**
         * If I create the constructor my field is not updated
         */
    }

}
```

In my controller

```
Class XYZController extends BaseModel 
{
    $emailModel = new EmailsModel() 
    $emailEdit  = $emailModel->find(1);
    $emailEdit->email = 'teste@test.com';
    $emailEdit->save() // $emailEdit->update()

    dd('end');
}
```

When I run this example without constructor my field "updated_by" is updated with ID the user, when I use the construtor the field does not update

What is the problem? I have no idea why updated_by by field is not updated with constructor.

Comment: `__construtor`? VTC for typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should follow the constructor signature in `Model.php`, which is:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    // ...
}
```

So, your `model` should be like this:

```
public function __construtor(array $attributes = [], $request = null)
{
    parent::__construct($attributes); // This is required

    $this->request = $request;
}
```

To get the parent's constructor be called, you must call `parent::__construct($attributes)` method because, `traits` booting are done in the `constructor` method in the `Model.php` file.

If you want to construct your model now then you may use something like this:

```
// Assumed you've $request in the scope
$emailModel = new EmailsModel([], $request);
```

To be more clear, check the `Model.php`, you'll see something like this:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->initializeTraits();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

In this case the, `bootIfNotBooted` method boots the traits so you need to call the parent constructor manually.

A suggestion: You don't need to pass the `$request` in the constructor, You can access the `Request` facade from the model if required. Maybe think about the design decision of your models. Also, there are methods available to create, update e.t.c, you can use those methods without manually constructing a model.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Its help me a lot, I never looked ithe constructor into the classe Model, I debugged the code and I don't found the answer. Thank you very much.
About the request I dont use inside the contructor, it is only a exemple. ;-)